# Playback in meetme (asterisk)

Tags: playback, asterisk

I would like to play an audio file to all members of a MeetMe conference, like a notification. Does anyone have any idea about how to do this?

Answer (score 5):

One easy way to do this is to have your asterisk system dial in (join) the the conference and then play the audio file then hangup.

The call file will look something like this:

```
Channel: Local/1000@default
Application: Playback
Data: sound_file
```

Just make that file with the appropriate values and the place it in the call directory. Asterisk with then make the call play back sound_file and the hangup.

Comment: It works, please let me know what part is not working. The best way to solve this would be to ignore the conference part of it first. See if you can make a call file that works. When that is working get it to join the conference.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the L-Option:

http://www.asterisk.org/docs/asterisk/trunk/applications/meetme